# Do there exist equidistributed countable subgroups in (compact) Lie groups?

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, equidistribution

By an equidistributed countable subgroup I mean a countable subgroup (with a finite or possibly countable set of generators) that is dense in $G$ such that for any sufficiently nice function (Haar measurable or stronger, although probably no stronger than continuous almost everywhere and (locally) bounded) you have
$$\int f(g)d\mu=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\left|W_n\right|}\sum_{g\in W_n}f(g)$$
where $W_n$ (in the finitely generated case) is the set of elements generated by products of $n$ generators (and their inverses) (in the infinitely generated case $W_n$ would be something like the set of words of length $n$ consisting of the first $n$ generators and their inverses, something to ensure $W_n$ is finite at each step).

I'm primarily interested in the finitely generated case for compact Lie groups. This is obvious for compact Abelian groups and I think it might be trivial for the infinitely generated case (just let the generators be an equidistributed sequence in $G$ or something).

Comment: First, if you're looking at compact Lie groups, then discrete subgroups will be finite, so you can remove the limit from the right side of your question. Second, seems to me that, given any discrete set in any smooth manifold, one can take a bump function of mass one supported away from the set. In particular this should provide a counterexample to your question, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: $U(1)$ has an infinite discrete subgroup generated by any irrational number (thinking of $U(1)$ as [0,1) with addition mod 1 as the group operation). I'm pretty sure that in general compact Lie groups have these kinds of subgroups but they aren't 'nice' in that the quotient group isn't a manifold.

Comment: Ah, you mean something different by "discrete subgroup" than I'm used to. In your example, I wouldn't call that a discrete subgroup since it's not, well, discrete in $U(1)$. Would you mind editing your definition into the question and we'll go from there?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That is a much more interesting question! :)

Comment: I found a relevant paper (http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183504263) but I don't think this rules out the possibility.